# font size setting doesn't work in ddd(data display debugger)

Tags: gnome, xorg, fonts

I have fresh-installed Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME lately, and installed `ddd` yesterday. The `ddd` font size is too small (12) so I changed the `defaultFontSize` value to `200` (from `120`, in units of 1/10 points) in the preferences, but it doesn't have any effect. I also tried setting `variableWidthFont` which the manual says *"is specified as an X font spec"*. It has no effect either.

This is the output when I start `ddd`:

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
(Annoyed?  Try 'Edit->Preferences->General->Suppress X Warnings'!)
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-170-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-r-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-*-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-*-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-300-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-symbol-*-*-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-adobe-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-*-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-*-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
```

Do I have to install any font package in Ubuntu 20.04 for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [warning when running ddd in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533838/warning-when-running-ddd-in-ubuntu) question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and it gave me the solution. Run:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi
```

and logout and log back in. Then you can see that the font size changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 (not just for `ddd`) and found that it is related to my new high-resolution monitor (3840x2160). As I do not need this high resolution for Ubuntu, I reduced it to 2560x1440 and everything is fine, including `ddd`.